# Deselecting DIVs (or textboxes) content after being selected by user

Tags: javascript, security, select

I would like to prepare a javascript-based system that would deselect the text after the user selects it. The reason for this is to protect some articles on my site from being stolen by just pressing ctrl+c pair. I know it's always possible to omit it, but it's at least a little harder. What is more, I can't use jQuery while writing this script. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My advice would be not to bother.  JavaScript can easily be disabled or manipulated using a script console, source can be viewed and copied, etc.  If anyone is going to steal those articles you won't be able to stop them without taking proper legal routes.  What's more, you're inconveniencing the folks who have a genuine need to copy and paste something, like a quote or a search term.

That being said, IE, Chrome and Safari all support the `onselectstart` event, which is cancellable:

```
element.onselectstart = function () { return false; }
```

Firefox supports its own CSS style, [`-moz-user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-user-select), which give the appearance that the text isn't selected, but doesn't disable it completely:

```
#element {
    -moz-user-select: none;
}
```

For Firefox, Opera and other browsers, however, there's no solution other than cancelling mousedown, double click and key events.  There would be no way of capturing and blocking "select all" from the browser's menu.

Comment: But that would probably make users unable to use the scrollbar, right?

Comment: @kremuwa: In some browsers (like Firefox), maybe.  Like I said in the first paragraph, it's just not a good idea.

Comment: Ok, but I'm pretty sure there is a way to deselect the text in textbox (using onSelect event) since I saw it somewhere - it would not make any problem with using the scrollbar and the "select all" option would be useless, too. Hmm? If there is no such option, I will resign.

Comment: @kremuwa i can't believe you are still considering this design mistake after Andy's post.

Comment: It's because actually it's not for me - my acquaintance asked me if there is a way to do such a thing. I wouldn't do that in my own work. It would be nice if you could remove your vote then.

Comment: @kremuwa: no, Firefox and Opera don't support such an event.